# Question about integration

Tags: integration, analysis, functional-analysis

I have this,

[image]

and I don't understand how to do the change of variable.

Please help me

Thank you.

Comment: You might want to check the Mean-Value theorem of integration. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem#First_mean_value_theorem_for_integration and chose $\varphi=1$

Comment: i dont understand how to use the mean-value theorem of integration

Comment: With $\varphi =1$ you find $\int_u^{u+w} 1 = w$ and $G(x)$ is in your notation $f(x)$ for $x\in(u,u+w)$ such a point can be written as $x=u+\theta w$. I suppressed the $t$ dependence of $f, u$ and $w$. Note that you apply the MVT for every $t$. Having said that, $\theta$ should be a function depending on $t$. But, since it is bounded your result will hold.

Comment: Also this is true and again, since the interval $[0,1]$ has mass one, you find by the MVT some $\theta*(t)$ with the desired properties

Comment: please @Quickbeam2k1 why $\theta$ should depend on t ? and who is bounded? thank you

Comment: It should depend on $t$ since you apply the MVT for every $t$! It is similar to the following $\int_0^1 f(u(t))-f(v(t)) dt=\int_0^1 f'(w(t))((u(t)-v(t)) dt$, where $w(t)\in (v(t),u(t))$ assuming that $v(t)<u(t)$. The $\theta$ is bounded between zero and one, or $w(t)$ is bounded between $v(t)$ and $u(t)$